# date format in selecting table for SQL database

Tags: mysql, database

i need to select * table rows where the order date is between 20/05/2011 and 19/05/2013

i'v already tried this

```
select * from commandes where datecmd < 20-05-2011 and datecmd > 19-05-2013
```

it returns no errors but i would like to know the best date format to work with all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQl query

```
SELECT * 
    FROM commandes 
    WHERE datecmd between convert(datetime,'20-05-2011',103) and convert(datetime,'19-05-2013',103)
```